# Why does the `\tikzpicture` shift outside the document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Everything works fine, till I am trying to draw the angles alpha, beta and gamma. By adding `\tkzMarkAngle` my sketch jumps to the second side and is swallowed to its half, as you can see in the screenshot below. I don't see the problem, what am I missing?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} % Defines the document as an article
\usepackage{tikz}                     % Graphic drawing library
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}              % Needed for "\usetkzobj{all}"
\usetkzobj{all}                       % Needed for "tkzMarkAngle" (tikz)
\begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.5, yscale=0.5]
% DEFINE_MAIN_FRAME_COORDINATES ------------------------------------------------
  \coordinate[label=below:$A1$] (A1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:$B1$] (B1) at (0,30);
  \coordinate[label=right:$C1$](C1) at (8,20.4);
% DRAW_MAIN_FRAME --------------------------------------------------------------
  \draw[line width=2pt][-] (C1) -- (B1) node [pos=0.5, right] {$a_1$};
  \draw[line width=2pt][-] (B1) -- (A1) node [pos=0.5, left]  {$c_1$};
  \draw[line width=2pt][-] (A1) -- (C1) node [pos=0.5, right] {$b_1$};
  \draw[dashed][-] (0,20.4) -- (C1) node [pos=0.5, above] {$h$};
% DRAW_ANGLES ------------------------------------------------------------------
  % alpha
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange, size=4, opacity=0.4](C1,A1,B1)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=3](C1,A1,B1){$\alpha$}
  % beta
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange, size=3, opacity=0.4](A1,B1,C1)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=2](A1,B1,C1){$\beta$}
  % gamma
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange, size=2, opacity=0.4](B1,C1,A1)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-1](B1,C1,A1){$\gamma$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

**Resulting output**:

[image]

I am grateful for any help, links, references and hints!

Comment: A4 paper is small for your coordinates. TikZ default is to use centimeters and you have a point at 15 cm after scaling. Page margins don't allow it to fit properly so it is pushed to the next and then gives up

Comment: Common problem with `tkz-euclide`, unfortunately. In some of the constructions it creates (invisible) paths that are far larger than the drawn diagram. Add the `overlay` option to each of the `\tkzMarkAngle`s, e.g. `\tkzMarkAngle[overlay,fill=orange, size=2, opacity=0.4](B1,C1,A1)`. See also the questions listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tkz-euclide+pgfinterruptboundingbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scale the figure by `0.5` as the dimensions are too large for an A4 paper. Also, using `angles,quotes` libraries makes drawing angles much easier.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} % Defines the document as an article
\usepackage{tikz}                     % Graphic drawing library
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}              % Needed for "\usetkzobj{all}"
%\usetkzobj{all}                       % Needed for "tkzMarkAngle" (tikz)
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
% DEFINE_MAIN_FRAME_COORDINATES ------------------------------------------------
  \coordinate[label=below:$A1$] (A1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:$B1$] (B1) at (0,30);
  \coordinate[label=right:$C1$] (C1) at (8,20.4);
% DRAW_MAIN_FRAME --------------------------------------------------------------
  \draw[line width=2pt] (C1) -- (B1) node [pos=0.5, right] {$a_1$}
                             -- (A1) node [pos=0.5, left]  {$c_1$}
                             -- (C1) node [pos=0.5, right] {$b_1$}
                             -- cycle;
  \draw[dashed] (0,20.4) -- (C1) node [pos=0.5, above] {$h$};
% DRAW_ANGLES ------------------------------------------------------------------
  % alpha
  \draw pic[draw,fill=orange!50,angle radius=2cm,"$\alpha$"] {angle=C1--A1--B1};
  % beta
  \draw pic[draw,fill=orange!50,angle radius=2cm,"$\beta$"] {angle=A1--B1--C1};
  % gamma
  \draw pic[draw,fill=orange!50,angle radius=1cm,"$\gamma$"] {angle=B1--C1--A1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document} %%%%%
```

[image]

Comment: `[scale=.5]` is equal to `[xscale=.5, yscale=.5]`. So it's gotta be something related to tkzmarkangle

Comment: @AboAmmar thanks! At first your solution didn't work because the command 
`\draw pic[draw,angle radius=2cm,"$\alpha$"] {angle=C1--A1--B1};` was 
interfering with the language package `\usepackage[ngerman.ldf]{babel}` and 
always threw the error message `! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an 
extra }.` But I was able to fix it by adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to the 
preamble.

Answer (score 1):

as supplement to [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59109/aboammar) answer with fully exploited `quotes` library and some small changes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale = 0.5,
     auto = right,
MA/.style = {% My Angle
            draw, fill=orange!50,
            angle radius=#1},
MA/.default = 16mm
                    ]
% coordinates
\coordinate[label=below:$A1$] (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=above:$B1$] (B1) at (0,30);
\coordinate[label=right:$C1$] (C1) at (8,20.4);
% angles' labels
\pic[MA,"$\alpha$"]     {angle=C1--A1--B1};
\pic[MA,"$\beta$"]      {angle=A1--B1--C1};
\pic[MA=8mm,"$\gamma$"] {angle=B1--C1--A1};
% triangle
\draw[line width=2pt] (C1) to ["$a_1$"] (B1)
                           to ["$c_1$"] (A1)
                           to ["$b_1$"] (C1)
                           -- cycle;
\draw[dashed]   (C1) to["$h$"] (C1 -| B1);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```